# How to use IF within map() in react to check which array element is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have something like this

```
const stuff = [
  { id: "1", col1: 232, col2: 232 },
  { id: "2", col1: 400, col2: 650 },
  { id: "2", col1: 300, col2: 300 },
];
```

Within my component's `return` function I have:

```
{chartData.map((item, index) =>
    <div>{item.col1}%</div>
)}
```

I have state which changed based on button press. e.g. `setColState('col2')` might be set after the corresponding button is hit.

I'd like to be able to switch between rendering `item.col1` and `item.col1` based on that. I've been trying different ways of achieving this with no luck. From embedding

```
{chartData.map((item, index) =>
    <div>if(ColState=="col2"){return item.col2}</div>
    )}
```

I tried a function that returns `<div>{return item.col2}</div>` and naming the state and array element the same so I can do `<div>{return item[ColState]</div>` but can't seem to get any to work.

I'm not using redux and ideally would avoid it as I'm a total react rookie.

Comment: Just make your arrow function run a function block instead of auto-returning a value due to using the one-liner syntax. I.e. instead of `blah.map(x => y)`, you use `blah.map(x => { do(); things(); here(); andThen(); return y })`.

Comment: You might also try a ternary `<div>{ColState=="col2" ? item.col2 : item.col1}</div>`.

Comment: Or this version was close `<div>{return item[ColState]</div>` just remove the `return` - `<div>{item[ColState]</div>`